# JavaScript changing HTML code after loading in a div

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page that gets values from a DB, I can't control the values / how they are called, but the end result looks like standard HTML code, for example:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="controls">
    <select id="jform_province" name="jform[province]">
        <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
        <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm looking to put a script at the end of the page that can modify the option elements by say adding a function so it looks like this:

```
<option value="AB" onClick="someFunction()">Alberta</option>
```

How can I modify the code? I know how to edit the entire content of the div but I want to change the elements, I will not know what the values of the elements are so the script needs to find all option tags in "myDiv" (I have other lists on the page I don't want changed) and add that code to all of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just attach an event handler:

```
document.getElementById('jform_province').onchange = function() {
  switch(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value) {
    case "AB": someFunction(); break;
    // define other cases as needed
  }
};
```

Note that `<option>` elements do not fire `onclick` events when selected, and even if they did it wouldn't detect alternate input methods such as using the keyboard. The code above provides an alternative.

Comment: The list does work on click but not on keypress so you are right, but the problem is that I don't always know what the options are going to be, in other cases it's just not feasible (there are hundreds of options), is there no way to automate this? What if I the function to be the same no matter which option is selected, how can I write that? Like case (all)

Comment: Then just don't put the `switch` there, just call the function.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great, the only thing is that I need to tab out of the drop list to update but that's ok.